# How to go about proving that $-1+(x-4)(x-3)(x-2)(x-1)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials, unique-factorization-domains

How do you show that $-1+(x-4)(x-3)(x-2)(x-1)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$?

I don't think you can use the eisenstein criterion here

Comment: Is that last factor $(-1)$ what was intended, or is it a typo for $(x-1)$?

Comment: @BrentKerby It was a typo, thanks!

Comment: It's not quick or glamorous, but multiply out the polynomial carefully, confirm no rational roots, then attempt to factor as $$ (x^2 + ax + b)(x^2 + cx + d)  $$ and confirm it cannot be done with integers $a,b,c,d.$ The main trick is shifted Eisenstein, taking $x = u + k$ and picking a good $k$ so that Eisenstein applies, but it may take a long time to find a $k$ that works, if ever. I prefer trial factoring, i think it teaches something.

Comment: Easier than I expected, the constant term makes a big restriction. Oh, Gauss lemma: "The second result states that if a non-constant polynomial with integer coefficients is irreducible over the integers, then it is also irreducible if it is considered as a polynomial over the rationals." +++++  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28polynomial%29

Comment: Notice that if you add 2 to this polynomial, so that the constant term changes from 23 to 25, the new polynomial factors into two quadratic terms very nicely. Anyway, worth doing both by hand, instructive and, now that I've done them myself, really not time consuming.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the obvious generalization is also true. Let $P$ and $Q$ be polynomial factors, so that the given expression equals $PQ$. Then $PQ=-1$ at each of the integer values, $1,2,3,4$ for this case. So $P,Q=\pm1$ at each of these integers, and whenever $P$ equals one, $Q$ equals minus one, and vice versa. But these are more than enough values to determine each polynomial, so $P=-Q$. But this is impossible because the coefficient of the highest order term in the product must be plus one.

Answer (score 1):

Another argument, special to this polynomial.

Any number of arguments (including multiplying the thing out) show that the polynomial is $\equiv X^4-2\pmod5$. Thus in characteristic $5$, any root is a $16$-th root of unity. But the smallest field of characteristic $5$ whose cardinality is $\equiv1\pmod{16}$ is $\Bbb F_{625}$. Thus the polynomial is already irreducible over $\Bbb F_5$, thus over $\Bbb Z$, thus over $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Gauss lemma as suggested, note that $1,2,3,4$ are clearly not roots of $p(x)$.  Also, when $x\leq 0$ or $x\geq 5$ we have $p(x)\geq -1+24>0$.  So there are no integer roots.  So $p$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ and hence $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: but 7 doesnot divide 71

Comment: It is also necessary to show that $p(x)$ cannot be the product of two quadratics.

Comment: still this wont work

Comment: for an example $(x^2+1)(x^2+2)$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}$...but it is reducible

Comment: So sorry.  So like the comment said, we need to expand out $(x^2+bx+c)(x^2+cx+d)$ and show this can never give $p(x)$ for integral $a,b,c,d$.  Looking at the constant term gives $a,b=\pm 1, \pm 23$, etc.

Comment: Torsion, right, if you want to give a full answer, it really is necessary to write out the conditions on the for coefficients and draw conclusions. Note that, if we add 2 to get constant term 25, very nice factors!

Comment: Torsion, in case it matters, my preference is that you work this out for your own but leave it as well for the OP to do. It is not hard, and the practice will do the OP a world of good. Perhaps you as well, haven't checked your background.